# react with spring boot white label error page in tomcat

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, white-labelling

How to redirect to correct react page with spring boot as back end in tomcat instead of showing white label error page?

I think my routing is not configured properly, can you please suggest the configuration steps.

I'm also stuck with Firefox browser in image upload (image upload works fine in chrome and opera)

Comment: Please add whatever you have done / what your configuration is, into the question so people can check what's causing your issues.

Comment: So did you use the `frontend-maven-plugin`? Also, tell us where exactly (code) the image upload doesn't work.